# vb.net Custom listbox add selectedindexchanged event

Tags: vb.net, themes

I currently have a custom ListBox control And I like the way it looks but it is missing the SelectedIndexChanged event. I tried to add it myself but I failed :/ So in short can someone help me add the SelectedIndexChanged event to the supplied listbox class?

```
Public Class Theme_ListBox
    Inherits Control

    '''I added this bit but it didnt work
    'Friend Event SelectedIndexChanged As EventHandler

    'Protected Overridable Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    '    RaiseEvent SelectedIndexChanged(Me, e)
    'End Sub

#Region "Variables"

    Private WithEvents ListB As New ListBox
    Private _Items As String() = {""}
    Private _BaseColour As Color = Color.FromArgb(42, 42, 42)
    Private _SelectedColour As Color = Color.FromArgb(55, 55, 55)
    Private _ListBaseColour As Color = Color.FromArgb(47, 47, 47)
    Private _TextColour As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)
    Private _BorderColour As Color = Color.FromArgb(35, 35, 35)

#End Region

#Region "Properties"

    <Category("Control")>
    Public Property Items As String()
        Get
            Return _Items
        End Get
        Set(value As String())
            _Items = value
            ListB.Items.Clear()
            ListB.Items.AddRange(value)
            Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property

    <Category("Colours")>
    Public Property BorderColour As Color
        Get
            Return _BorderColour
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            _BorderColour = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Category("Colours")>
    Public Property SelectedColour As Color
        Get
            Return _SelectedColour
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            _SelectedColour = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Category("Colours")>
    Public Property BaseColour As Color
        Get
            Return _BaseColour
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            _BaseColour = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Category("Colours")>
    Public Property ListBaseColour As Color
        Get
            Return _ListBaseColour
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            _ListBaseColour = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Category("Colours")>
    Public Property TextColour As Color
        Get
            Return _TextColour
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            _TextColour = value
        End Set
    End Property



    Public ReadOnly Property SelectedItem() As String
        Get
            Return ListB.SelectedItem
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property SelectedIndex() As Integer
        Get
            Return ListB.SelectedIndex
            If ListB.SelectedIndex < 0 Then Exit Property
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Clear()
        ListB.Items.Clear()
    End Sub

    Public Sub ClearSelected()
        For i As Integer = (ListB.SelectedItems.Count - 1) To 0 Step -1
            ListB.Items.Remove(ListB.SelectedItems(i))
        Next
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateControl()
        MyBase.OnCreateControl()
        If Not Controls.Contains(ListB) Then
            Controls.Add(ListB)
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub AddRange(ByVal items As Object())
        ListB.Items.Remove("")
        ListB.Items.AddRange(items)
    End Sub

    Sub AddItem(ByVal item As Object)
        ListB.Items.Remove("")
        ListB.Items.Add(item)
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Draw Control"

    Sub Drawitem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ListB.DrawItem
        If e.Index < 0 Then Exit Sub
        e.DrawBackground()
        e.DrawFocusRectangle()
        With e.Graphics
            .SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
            .PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
            .InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            .TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit
            If InStr(e.State.ToString, "Selected,") > 0 Then
                .FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(_SelectedColour), New Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height - 1))
                .DrawString(" " & ListB.Items(e.Index).ToString(), New Font("Segoe UI", 9, FontStyle.Bold), New SolidBrush(_TextColour), e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y + 2)
            Else
                .FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(_ListBaseColour), New Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height))
                .DrawString(" " & ListB.Items(e.Index).ToString(), New Font("Segoe UI", 8), New SolidBrush(_TextColour), e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y + 2)
            End If
            .Dispose()
        End With
    End Sub

    Sub New()
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or ControlStyles.UserPaint Or
            ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw Or ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)
        DoubleBuffered = True
        ListB.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
        ListB.ScrollAlwaysVisible = False
        ListB.HorizontalScrollbar = False
        ListB.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
        ListB.BackColor = _BaseColour
        ListB.Location = New Point(3, 3)
        ListB.Font = New Font("Segoe UI", 8)
        ListB.ItemHeight = 20
        ListB.Items.Clear()
        ListB.IntegralHeight = False
        Size = New Size(130, 100)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim B As New Bitmap(Width, Height)
        Dim G = Graphics.FromImage(B)
        Dim Base As New Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height)
        With G
            .SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
            .PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
            .TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit
            .Clear(BackColor)
            ListB.Size = New Size(Width - 6, Height - 5)
            .FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(_BaseColour), Base)
            .DrawRectangle(New Pen(_BorderColour, 3), New Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height - 1))
        End With
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        G.Dispose()
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(B, 0, 0)
        B.Dispose()
    End Sub

#End Region



End Class
```

Comment: Firstly, do you know how to raise your own events?  If not, go and research that.  I've written a blog post about it specifically.  http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html

Comment: I read your post and understood about 5% of it (im dumb)

Comment: Your event should be `Public`.  Your `OnSelectedIndexChanged` method looks right.  You now just need to call that method and pass `EventArgs.Empty` when the value of the `SelectedIndex` has changed.

Comment: I'm a little confused as how to go about doing that properly

Comment: You're a little confused as to how to call a method and pass an argument?  Try `OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs.Empty)`.

Comment: Yes... Where am I to call it inside the form? in the class? how does this = selectedindexchanged when i never once coded anything that gets the current selectedindex? Im just a little confused as to how the OnSelectedIndexChanged sub actually knows its changed? 

The only code I have currently for Selectedindex is:

    Public Event SelectedIndexChanged As EventHandler

    Public Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent SelectedIndexChanged(Me, e)
    End Sub

Comment: and it doesnt do anything even if i do 

Private Sub Theme_ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Theme_ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        MessageBox.Show("Event")
    End Sub

Comment: @jmcilhinney I still have not figured it out :/ how do I know when the selected index has changed?